# Can you do FROM or INNER JOIN on things that are not a table?

Tags: sql

Can you

```
select * from (select * from table1)
```

or

```
select * from (select * from table1 where id=1) inner join (select * from table1 where id=1)
```

I am not asking for alternative ways to do these problems, I am just discussing the possibility of above operations. Thank you.

Comment: just add a table alias and you can do both of them. Of course inner join need a `on` operator

Comment: They're called subquery

Comment: JamieD77, they're actually called derived tables. Yes you can do that Dylan...just give the table an alias like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1) a INNER JOIN .... (SELECT ...) b ON a.id <> b.id`...or something like that.

Comment: yes, you can. as you see in your own example

Comment: 1st query OK. 2nd syntax error, missing ON clause. (http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/)